# how to select this class in php?

Tags: php

php:

```
class MyClass
{
    const CONSTANT = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::CONSTANT . "\n";
    }
}

echo MyClass::CONSTANT . "\n"; //this way selects MyClass.
```

My question is that could I select this class as following:

```
echo $this->CONSTANT . "\n"; // I think it's not right way, how could I do?
```

I want to select current class.

I'm very new to php and while learning php this question came into my mind. So forgive me If I'm asking nonsense question.

Comment: Instantiate the class first, thne call the method, which seems that is doing the echo, no need of another echo

Comment: Why do you want to access a *constant* in such a way?

Comment: This question won my chart for plenty of different WRONG answers and bad practices

Comment: A constant is accessible through a class, not its object, which is an instantiation of a class.

Comment: You don't access constants using `->` operator. You do it with `::` operator. It doesn't matter what you *want*, what matters is learning how things work. You can create a function that returns the constant, and then you could use `$object->showConstant();`. If you want direct access then you use `MyClass::CONSTANT`. That's it.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for your comment for clear concept

Answer (score 2):

`CONST` properties are accessible without the need of instantiating the class.

`CONST` are also shared across all the instances of the class in memory.

To access a `CONST`:

`ClassName::CONST`

or given a class referenced in a variable:

`$myclassvar::CONST`

Or in class Context:

`self::CONST`

This is well explained here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    const CONSTANT = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::CONSTANT . "\n";
    }
}

echo MyClass::CONSTANT . "\n";

$classname = "MyClass";
echo $classname::CONSTANT . "\n"; // As of PHP 5.3.0

$class = new MyClass();
$class->showConstant();

echo $class::CONSTANT."\n"; // As of PHP 5.3.0
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<?php
 $a = new MyClass();
 echo $a::CONSTANT;
?>
```